# Add foreign key to table after migration has been run in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following migration in my Laravel migrations folder that I have already run:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAdminTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        Schema::create('Admin' , function($table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->mediumText('title');
            $table->text('blog_content');
            $table->char('tag' , 15);
        });
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        Schema::drop('Admin');
    }
}
```

The above migration is for my `admin` table, what I would really like to do is add a foreign key in my `admin` table that is associated with my `tags` table. Something like:

```
 $table->foreign('tag')->references('tag')->on('tags');
```

How do I do this now that I have already run my migration?

### Edit

I tried the following:

STEP 1: deleted the `tag` column from the `admin` table from phpMyAdmin.

STEP 2: Tried running the following migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddForeignKeyTagsColumn extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('Admin', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->char('tag' , 15)->after('slug');
            $table->foreign('tag')->references('tag')->on('tags');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        // Schema::drop('Admin');
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

[image]

Why is the foreign key unable to be created?

Comment: Regarding your edit. Is your table encoding myisam / innodb? try changing it to innodb as myisam does not support foreign keys.

Comment: @Gravy changed the following in config/database.php `'engine' => "InnoDB",` .. deleted and recreated all tables but i still get the error , that `
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key
tag_foreign` foreign key (`tag`) references `tags` (`tag`))` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrations are version control for your db. There is no point in writing migrations if you don't intend to use the version control functionality.

So simply, you can alter the table by creating a new migration... from the command line:

`php artisan make:migration alter_table_admin_add_foreign_tag`

Then in your new migration, do your up and down methods.

Once your migration is ready, `php artisan migrate`.

REGARDING EDITED QUESTION:

Both tables need to be `innodb` and not `myisam`. Further, both columns parent key and relation key need to be the same data type. As such, in your `tags` table is also configured with `$table->char('tag' , 15);`

SIDE NOTE / suggestion:

Why do you have some tables singular and some plural. and why do you have some tables starting with a capital letter, and other tables in lower case? `Admin` could be `admins` and `tags` could remain `tags` for consistency.

Comment: i changed the tables to be innodb , also i added same datatypes for `tag` feild , still unable to create the foreign key , i still get an error http://imgur.com/a/AWunG

Comment: is your table name `admin` or `Admin`?

Answer (score -2):

Create a new migration with the following code:

```
public function up() {
    Schema::table('Admin' , function($table){
        $table->foreign('tag')->references('tag')->on('tags'); 
    });
}

public function down() {
    Schema::table('Admin' , function($table){
        $table->dropForeign('Admin_tag_foreign'); 
    });
}
```

Then run `php artisan migrate`